# Laravel api routing issue: Route [login] not defined

Tags: laravel-passport, laravel-10, laravel-api

I am using Laravel as back end for my project. Passport package is being used for authentication of api request. But I am getting error for login.

Kindly suggest me what and where I am missing.

Following is my code from my routes/api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthUser;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::controller(AuthUser::class)->group(function () {
    Route::post('login', 'login');
    Route::post('logout', 'logout');
});
```

Postman response below

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined. in file C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 467

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(808): Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator->route('login', Array, true)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php(15): route('login')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php(96): App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate->redirectTo(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php(81): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->unauthenticated(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php(55): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->authenticate(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 'api')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(798): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(777): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(741): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(730): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\public\index.php(51): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\ERP-V.2.0.0\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\resources\server.php(16): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#32 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message states a missing route called `'login'`. This is not related to the Route declaration itself, and trying to reach an unexisting route would probably throw `405 Method Not Allowed`. Taking a closer look to your error stack dump you'll find the exact point on which the error is thrown. What happened was:

1. The `Authenticate` middleware was evoked and restricted the request because no user was logged in;
2. Authenticate middleware tried redirecting to a route called `login` – this is not the same as 'POST /login', the `route()` function expects a route alias (called *name*), not a route URI. See [Generating URLs To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes);
3. No 'login' named route is defined, thus throwing that error.

First of all: **Why is Authenticate controller getting in the way?** The login route should be public, so it doesn't make sense to have it on that route. My guess is: Your HTTP Kernel has it set globally. Take a look there and make sure it is not global; it is not default to API group; it is not in your controller's constructor; *etc*.

Finally, how to define the `login` named route? I guess this link should be enough: [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#named-routes)

```
Route::get('/user/profile', function () {
    // ...
})->name('profile');
```

**Fun Fact!** As a matter of fact, we have [an open PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/47317) for Laravel 11.x to remove the assumption that a `login` route exists.